# URL constructor returns `nil` in Swift

Tags: swift, url, appcode

I am new to `Swift` and running some app under `AppCode`. And it looks for me, that something strange is happening: legal `URL` turns to `nil` in constructor.

This is a watch in debugger:

[image]

Why can it be?

Comment: it is just a [bug](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-12444) **A number of other types fail to display correctly in the Varibles
Pane and also fail to print correctly with frame v and print. They do
print correctly with po. These include Date, TimeZone, URL, Calendar
DateComponents, IndexPath. I haven't tested every type so others
probably fail as well.**

Comment: Incredible. Thanks.

Comment: you are welcome

Comment: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-11593 is a better one to look at, good discussion of the underlying causes